# Yammer OAUTH 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant

Tags: yammer

Does Yammer support Yammer OAUTH 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant as suggested in the RFC - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The supported flows for OAuth with Yammer are documented at https://developer.yammer.com/authentication/. This flow is generally only supported by first party apps for any service that supports OAuth because credentials are entered directly in the application.